# Read MongoDB results and use in SH shell script to create symbolic link

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu, sh

I have a **MongoDB** collection filled with dummy data for a demo.
I have an image file in a folder called example.jpg
For each ID in the collection I want to create a symlink from ID.jpg to example.jpg

For example if the collection holds 3 documents with ids of 345kjh34k5, 8945ng49, and 3459t8u34 I want to create 3 symbolic links of 345kjh34k5.jpg, 8945ng49.jpg and 3459t8u34.jpg that all point to example.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to create a mongo script prints the ids, then have a bash script that loops through it and creates a link for each id.

Here's some code for it.

#### Setup - create Mongodb Dummy collection

```
db = connect("test");
db.dummy.insert({ _id : "345kjh34k5" });
db.dummy.insert({ _id : "8945ng49" });
db.dummy.insert({ _id : "3459t8u34" });
```

#### Setup - Create sample file

Filename: file1.txt

```
File1 content. Blah blah blah.
```

#### MongoDB script print dummy ids

Filename: printDummyIds.js

```
db = connect("test");
var linkNames = db.dummy.find().map(function(doc){
        print( doc._id );
});
```

Output:

```
mongo --quiet printDummyIds.js 
345kjh34k5
8945ng49
3459t8u34
```

#### Bash script that calls mongo then creates soft links

Filename: createLinksFromIds.sh

```
echo Linking files to source.
echo Source: $1
ext="${1#*.}"
out="./out/"
mkdir $out
for id in $(mongo --quiet printDummyIds.js) 
do 
    lName=$out$id"."$ext ;
    echo Creating $lName ;
    ln -s $1 $lName ;
done
```

#### Usage

```
createLinksFromIds.sh FILE_PATH
FILE_PATH is the file that you want to link.
```

Example:

```
bash createLinksFromIds.sh file1.txt
```

Output:

```
Linking files to source.
Source: file1.txt
Creating ./out/345kjh34k5.txt
Creating ./out/8945ng49.txt
Creating ./out/3459t8u34.txt
```